# Top command Android 8

Tags: android, linux, cpu-usage, top-command

I am trying to read (and understand) the CPU usage provided by the `top` command in my Samsung Galaxy S7.

From another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134190/descrip-top-command-in-android) I can see the explanation of the `top` command with the output that this person is getting.

However, when I go inside my Samsung using `adb shell` and I cal the `top` command, what I get is different from what the other used posted.

Am I doing something different/wrong?

If not, **how do I read this output from `top`??**

The output from the user on the other post has this:

```
User 5%, system 15%, IOW 0%, IRQ 0%
User 5 + Nice 0 + Sys 14 + Idle 73 + IOW 0 + IRQ 0 + SIRQ 0 = 92
PID     CPU%  S   #THR    VSS    RSS    UID     Name
213     11%   R    1      900K   340K   app_16   top
```

However, the output from my top gives me something like that:

```
Tasks: 371 total,   7 running, 359 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie                                                               
Mem:   3618604k total,  3545056k used,    73548k free,   118980k buffers                                                           
Swap:  2097148k total,   894520k used,  1202628k free,  1441660k cached                                                            
800%cpu   9%user   0%nice  11%sys 780%idle   0%iow   0%irq   0%sirq   0%host
```

Basically, I cannot see the row

```
User 5%, system 15%, IOW 0%, IRQ 0%
```

which seems to be the key to understand the CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why, but "top" command is not longer accepting params on Android 8

Comment: They [moved](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/4558428ae83194269bdb3b50f92dba1f2690a6ba) it from their own "[toolbox](https://elinux.org/Android_toolbox)" program to [toybox](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/toybox/+/refs/heads/master/toys/posix/ps.c). Idk then about details, but at least on my Pie phone it has all the commands that you could wish for.